# connecting to server in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I want to connect a server with the following configuration:

```
 Host <name>

  HostName <IP_Address>
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_ssh.txt
```

VS code returns an error:

```
Could not establish connection to <name>
```

and stocks when it connects to the VS code server. However, I can connect to the server in VS code terminal using `ssh <name>`. I could not solve this issue, I can connect using the terminal but not by using `Remote-SSH connect to host`.

Does anyone have any ideas? It is the full error message:

```
   [02:05:12.309] Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying
[02:05:13.325] Resolver error: Error: 
    at m.Create (c:\Users\h_jal\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:584145)
    at c:\Users\h_jal\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:644535
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\h_jal\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:647428)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\h_jal\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:645160)
    at async c:\Users\h_jal\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:720916
[02:05:13.339] ------
```

Comment: @topsail It was a typo when I wanted to copy the config file here. Sorry. I edited the text.

Comment: "Resolver error" is a DNS failure.  Is that machine actually known as `<name>` on your network?  Can you ping it?

Comment: @TimRoberts <name> is not my virtual machine name, the VM name is ZBP_VM. The config file works in command line but not with Remote-SSH.

Comment: You misunderstand.  If you want to do `ssh xyz`, then `xyz` has to be findable through DNS.  You could `ssh ip-address`, I suppose.

Comment: @TimRoberts IP address has been defined before in the configuration file. The issue is not ssh xyz in the command line because it works.

Comment: You are assuming that VSCode is using the same ssh config file that command line ssh uses.  Unlike Linux, Windows is not that regular.  VSCode might have its own ssh with its own configuration files.  Does it work if you tell VSCode the IP address?